# How to query data from million records of data with date column?

Tags: sql

I have a table called "ErrorLog" in my SQL database where the data needs to be copied to Azure blob. I need full table data, so I used "`select * from ErrorLog where LogDate > 2017-01-01`"

This query is taking too much time (Hours), is there any better way to optimize this query? Table is already indexed with Id and also set as Primary key.

Comment: Note that `2017-01-01` is not a date, it's a subtraction with the result 2015.

Comment: The LogDate column needs an index too.

Comment: How to create an index, sorry I have only read access to that database. Any other way?

Comment: Kindly ask the DBA to create the index?

Comment: How many rows do you expect the query to select? If it's selecting milions of rows, it will take time...

Comment: It is around 12 million records!

Comment: To move large amounts of data you are better to use database utilities, which are engineered to work at scale.

Comment: It looks like LogDate column need to be partitioned column  if frequently queried with it.